# Mass spectrometry: systematic mathematic transformation for calibration

Tags: analytical-chemistry, mass-spectrometry

Given a NaI mass calibration in the m/z 300-2000 range on a QTOF instrument as shown below:
 [image]

and given any *uncalibrated* mass spectrum that has been measured with the same instrument settings. What is a general mathematical transformation that calibrates the mass spectrum to the NaI calibration. masses of the NaI clusters are of course known, i.e.

[image]

Overall, it seems the masses always deviate by about 0.1 m/z by being always a little bit too high than the reference in this case.

My question now is, how a simple mathematical approach could look like to calibrate mass spectra using the NaI reference. The simplest approach would be to just create a peak list out of the NaI spectrum, i.e. 
472.8, 622.7, 772.6, ..., 1971.7
and perform a linear fit against the calculated NaI masses, i.e.
472.7, 622.6, 772.5, ..., 1971.6.

Which looks like this:

[image]

Where the slope of the line is 1.00003175282 and the intercept is
-0.153462368663.

Because the overall mass range is high, while the variations in mass are of course small, this gives the ridiculously high $R^2$ of 0.999999999556.

Now I could just apply this linear function

f(m/z) = m/z * slope + intercept

to uncalibrated mass spectra. Is this simple approach viable? Because it does not take into account that the mass deviation might be different depending on the m/z region. From your experience, is it likely for a QTOF-instrument to show significantly different mass deviations in different mass regions? Would it be better to make a "polygonal chain" and divide the overall mass range in separate regions instead?

Comment: You already have a tremendously good fit to your data. Try using chi squared instead of $R^2$ (which is useless btw) as then you can work out probability a good fit, see Bevington 'Data reduction and error analysis for the physical science' or Press,  Teukolsky,  Vetterling and  Flannery; 'Numerical Recipes'. You can only really know how TOFms works outside the calibration region by experiment. Otherwise you can only hope that the response is linear.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. 'You can only know how TOFms works outside the calibration region' I just want to add that I don't intent to measure outside the calibration region (i.e. no extrapolation, only interpolation). Thanks for the references, I will have a look : )

Comment: Basically, I am unsure if the normal instrument calibration on a QTOF device is just a rescaling of the m/z scale or if it also includes some other internal adjustments. Because the typical calibration procedure are very tedious and if they are basically just a linear transformation on the m/z scale, Id rather just apply this change during postprocessing ...

Comment: The Waters calibration procedure (for Waters Q-TOF) is a polynomial fit (to the fourth or fifth order, I would need to check). The linear fit is quite good, as you show, but if you intend to really measure with ppm accuracy, you might need a better fit of the calibration curve. You should try to plot the residuals (difference between calibrated mass and reference points as a function of m/z) to see if there appears to be a systematic deviation from the linear fit on one edge or the other.

Comment: @PLD That's a good idea. I will just try it out and see if I get a good calibration like this and I will plot the difference between calibrated mass and reference points as a function of m/z then.